# Oracle SOA Suite 11g installation problems

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, soa, oracle-soa, soa-suite

I am trying to install Oracle SOA Suite 11g but I face the following problem during  installation. There are some prerequisites marked as failed. I am wondering why the overall result of the check is not executed. In addition, I have a problem starting the SOA managed server later.

[image]

I cannot see the "SOA" folder here

[image]

Comment: We could probably use the details under the "Checking service pack" node that you haven't expanded. Could you reupload the image with the node expanded?

Comment: The error is the same as the "Checking operating system configuration"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, if you ignore the checks and SOA does not appear something is broken. You need to tell us your OS version and make sure you adhere to the installation instructions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/nav/ipu.htm). My guess is you're on some linux distro. There are many files that need to be installed in many cases on linux to make this work.

I suggest, unless you *have to* install directly on your OS, to use a prebuilt virtual image to get up and running quickly. 
SOA Suite 12c prebuilt is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/learnmore/vmsoa1213-2660211.html). Install virtual box (free) and then follow download instructions exactly.
[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/learnmore/vmsoa-172279.html) is 11g.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use Windows 8.1 Pro. I think that It is highly recommended to install everything directly on my OS, because Oracle SOA Suite and the other related tools are used for a small project based on a sample tutorial.

Comment: You still do not indicate version of product you are using which makes it very hard to help you. Win81. is only supported for 11.1.1.9+ per the certification matrix here - which you should look at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html.  Still not sure why you want to waste your time installing the product when the VM comes pre-configured.  If you insist on installing it all by hand, have you tried to follow the Oracle blog on how to do a windows install? https://blogs.oracle.com/SOA/entry/installing_oracle_soa_suite_11

Comment: The products are: Oracle SOA Suite (11.1.1.5.0). Repository Creation Utility (11.1.1.5.0)

Comment: The tutorial which I follow is from the book ''Getting Started With Oracle SOA Suite 11g R1 – A Hands-On Tutorial'' https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/getting-started-oracle-soa-suite-11g-r1-%E2%80%93-hands-tutorial

Comment: I answered above. Windows 8.1 is *not* supported on versions prior to 11.1.1.9. So, you are likely running into compatibility problems with a release that is not supported on that OS. You are using a version 4 releases back from current production. You can use any 11 or 12 version for the tutorial. You can use the VMs as well. No difference except they will work out of the box and you will not have the setup issues.  If you insist on installing your own SOA Suite, use a version certified for your OS.

Comment: I tried to install version 11.1.1.9 and everything works well for now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle recommends ignoring the results of these checks for some of it's products, although I couldn't find a specific reference to SOA product, you can try to just go ahead and continue with the installation, hoping it will run successfully.

Here's is a reference to Oracle's reference for installation issues - 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e14771/install.htm#BABCCGAB
You can find an instruction to ignore these errors under the 2.1.6 Oracle Universal Installer Issues section, although I'm not sure they apply in your case.

Comment: I skip the prerequisites checks and finish the installation. When I run the soa server there are exceptions thrown. When I open the Enterprise Manager, I cannot see the SOA directory in the domain tree on the left side of the page.